# Delete AWS IAM user that has a certain tag only, using Cloudformation (Condition)

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

I am trying to allow IAM users (OperationsAdmin) within a certain group (OperationsAdmin group) the ability to delete users that have a certain tag (a tag that specifies that admin created the user).

Is this something that is possible to do within Cloudformation? I have tried this but it is not working. Other admin users in other admin groups are able to delete users they should not be able to. Any thoughts on doing this through cloudformation, using yaml?

```
  OperationsUserGroupAdmin:
Type: AWS::IAM::Group
Properties:
  GroupName: !Sub OperationsUserGroupAdmin-${StackName}
  Path: "/"
  Policies:
    - PolicyName: !Sub OperationsUserGroupAdminPolicy-${StackName}
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - "iam:AddUserToGroup"
              - "iam:RemoveUserFromGroup"
            Resource:
              - !Sub "arn:aws:iam::*:group/OperationsUserGroup-${StackName}"
          - Effect: Allow
            Sid: DeleteUser
            Action:
              - "iam:DeleteUser"
            Resource: 'arn:aws:iam::*:user/*'
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                aws:RequestTag/CreatedBy:
                  - OperationsAdmin
```

Comment: I should add that the adding and removing of users from groups works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer. Basically, I was using the incorrect condition. I should have been using "aws:ResourceTag":

```
          - Effect: Allow
            Sid: DeleteUser
            Action:
              - "iam:DeleteUser"
            Resource: 'arn:aws:iam::*:user/*'
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                aws:ResourceTag/CreatedBy:
                  - OperationsAdmin
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#:%7E:text=ab12%2D22222222/%22%5D%0A%7D%7D-,aws%3AResourceTag/tag%2Dkey,-Works%20with%20string:%7E:text=ab12%2D22222222/%22%5D%0A%7D%7D-,aws%3AResourceTag/tag%2Dkey,-Works%20with%20string